Error message--how to deconstruct and read
I'm new to coding, and I am not able to understand the error message in Eclipse,
Can you please tell me the steps to read an error message?
    enter code herejuin 30, 2024 6:28:23 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 126
juin 30, 2024 6:28:23 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 126.0.6478.115. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.16.1` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
juin 30, 2024 6:28:28 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 126
juin 30, 2024 6:28:28 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 126.0.6478.115. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.16.1` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '22'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, findElement {using=xpath, value=//body/div[@id='product-category']/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 126.0.6478.115, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 126.0.6478.126 (d36ace6122e..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Kamilia\AppData\Lo...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:59740}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:59740/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 126.0.6478.115, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:152)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:523)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:354)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:194)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:627)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:624)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:204)
    at SeleniumShoping.main(SeleniumShoping.java:32)


The error message comes from the application you run at seems not related to Eclipse, the IDE you use to write your code. The error messages says You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.16.1 where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's. Please show your project dependencies (e.g. if it's a Maven project, add the content of your pom.xml file as text into your question).

 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Link 1
Link 2
Link 3
Hope it helps.
Ignore the sentences start with "warning" words of selenium, read sentences after it. If you want to know where your code is wrong, look at the error lines relate to your current code file (file name, functions), such as at SeleniumShoping.main(SeleniumShoping.java:32) => your line 32 is error in your SeleniumShoping.java file
